# Is there a way to make "Find All" run dynamic searches in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

For example I want to find all classes that contain the method tag "[Test]" but lack the class tag "[TestFixture]".

I know a simple Google search can do things like...
'bass -fish'  Will return bass guitars etc. with the bass fish stuff excluded.

I'd guess I want something like '[Test] AND ![TestFixture]'

Of course the search treats that like a single string and finds nothing.

Any ideas? :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would of course require a search which understands what a class is. Not at all trivial in C++, for instance, But somehow I suspect you mean C# classes.

Comment: I do indeed work in C# as you suspect :) Give or take a few partial classes, we're mostly organized as one class per file. 'Find All' already groups results by file so this shouldn't be too much of a concern.